# How does automatic inheritance from collections.Callable (and other classes) work?

Tags: python, inheritance, collections, operator-overloading

This is more of a Python 2 question, but I'm curious about whether there are any differences in Python 3 as well.

I noticed that when creating certain methods on class (whether they are new-style or not), Python automatically decides that those classes are instances of some classes from the collections module. My example below demonstrates this with collections.Callable.

```
>>> import collections
>>> class A:
        def __call__(self):
                print "A"


>>> a = A()
>>> isinstance(a, collections.Callable)
True
>>> class A(object):
        def __call__(self):
                print "A"


>>> a = A()
>>> isinstance(a, collections.Callable)
True
>>> class A(object):
        pass

>>> a = A()
>>> isinstance(a, collections.Callable)
False
>>> class A:
        pass

>>> a = A()
>>> isinstance(a, collections.Callable)
False
```

You'll notice that I haven't explicitly made any of those classes inherit from collections.Callable, but for some reason they all do as long as they create a `__call__` method. **Is this done for a specific purpose and is it well defined somewhere? Is Python automatically giving classes certain base classes just for defining methods or is something else going on?**

You'll get similar results for collections.Iterable and the `__iter__` method and some other special methods as well.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html, in particular [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__), and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).

Answer (score 0):

The `ABCMeta` class implements [hooks to customize instance and subclass checks](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks); both `__instancecheck__()` and `__subclasscheck__()` are provided.

These hooks delegate to the [`ABCMeta.__subclasshook__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__):

> `__subclasshook__(subclass)`
>
> Check whether *subclass* is considered a subclass of this ABC. This means that you can customize the behavior of `issubclass` further without the need to call `register()` on every class you want to consider a subclass of the ABC.

This hook then can check if a given subclass implements the expected methods; for `Callable` the [implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a985b6455fde/Lib/_abcoll.py#l128) simply has to see if there is a `__call__` method present:

```
@classmethod
def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
    if cls is Callable:
        if _hasattr(C, "__call__"):
            return True
    return NotImplemented
```

This is restricted to the specific `Callable` class; subclasses will have to implement their own version as you most likely would add methods.